# Node-WebSpider: Unreadable code from response data

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Hi I am writing a crwaler for Skyscanner, and the response show in CMD is

> unreadable code While res.statusCode = 200

Please share your opinion with this case.

```js
const https = require("https");
var querystring = require("querystring"); 

var postData = querystring.stringify({
 "adults":1,
 "children":0,
 "adultsv2":1,
 "childrenv2":"",
 "infants":0,
 "cabinclass":"economy",
 "rtn":0,
 "preferdirects":false,
 "outboundaltsenabled":false,
 "inboundaltsenabled":false,
 "ref":"day-view"
});


var options = {
    hostname: "www.skyscanner.com.hk",
 port: 443,
 path:"/transport/flights/can/chc/170604/airfares-from-guangzhou-to-christchurch-in-june-2017.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=day-view",
 // method:"GET",
 headers:{
  "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
  "Accept-Language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
  "Referer":"https://www.skyscanner.com.hk/transport/flights/can/chc/170604/airfares-from-guangzhou-to-christchurch-in-june-2017.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=day-view",
  "Connection":"keep-alive",
  "Host":"www.skyscanner.com.hk",
  "Cookie":'X-Mapping-fpkkgdlh=A68441A39FD59AA2C4E51F7090677B32; scanner=adults:::1&originalAdults:::1&adultsV2:::1&children:::0&originalChildren:::0&infants:::0&originalInfants:::0&charttype:::1&rtn:::false&preferDirects:::false&includeOnePlusStops:::true&cabinclass:::Economy&tripType:::one-way&ncr:::false&lang:::EN&currency:::HKD&outboundAlts:::false&inboundAlts:::false&usrplace:::HK&from:::CAN&to:::CHC&oym:::1706&oday:::04&wy:::0&iym:::1706&iday:::04&legs:::CAN%7C2017-06-04%7CCHC%7C%7C%7C&childrenV2:::&fromCy:::CN&toCy:::NZ; ssculture=locale:::en-GB&currency:::HKD&market:::HK; ssab=Fss_groupMessaging_V3:::b&Ads_UseESIAds_V1:::b&Hfe_PricePerNight_V2:::b&Car_GooglePlaces_V10:::b&scaffold_wireup_dont_delete_V1:::b&hbe_sorting_V9:::a&FlightsHeroImage_GG_27_06_2016_57_51_V2:::a&Apps_ErrorLogging_Android_V5:::on&Xsell_HomeReturningMessageIt2_V2:::d&Hsc_ChildrenAgeView_V10:::b&AVGS_Android_TopDealsCaret_V1:::on&use_contentful_for_seo_pages_EnabletraffictoCFBAAirlinepage_17_10_2016_50_49_V3:::b&AVGS_iOS_ScreenshotSharing_ShortenerVariation_V1:::c&FlightsHeroStraplineUpper_ConfidencemessageforIN_06_09_2016_42_06_V2:::c&fps_directionalpricing_V2:::b&BPK150_NewPrimaryButtonDesign_V2:::b&FlightsiOSProdTest_V2:::a&INS1887_ConsumeStoredPricesOnBV_V9:::b&AEP_SEOPageUniversalLinksExperiment_TR_V3:::on&GHT617_FlightDurationOnBrowse_V2:::a&UtidTravellerIdentity_V11:::b&Car_AATest_V4:::a&INS1846_PerDayDirectness_V1:::b&WebApps_GrapplerMPLogging_V9:::b&GHT571_HomepageDiscoveryShelvesRollOut_V7:::a&INS1683_BrowseUpdating_V6:::b&FlightsAndroidProdTest_V1:::b&Car_AWS_API_V24:::b&Hsc_MexicanToAS2_V4:::b&fps_grappler_V7:::b&AFS_DayView_Firebase_NPS_V10:::off&fbw_paypalEnabled_V2:::a&AfsKeywordsSelection_V1:::b&FlightsHeroImage_US_19_07_2016_10_08_V2:::b&EPS825_BrowseOverNNLowestPrice_V7:::a&FlightsHeroImage_US_25_07_2016_40_13_V2:::b&INS1964_MVProfileChange_V2:::b&INS1606_IndicativeResultsView_V1:::a&fps_sessionstate_V8:::b&Apps_ErrorLogging_iOS_V6:::on&FlightsHeroImage_BR_05_07_2016_33_21_V1:::b&FAB_DayviewCTA_Colour_V1:::a&FlightsHeroStraplineLower_PRE_PRODHeroimagechangefortheUSmarket_03_05_2016_00_40_V1:::a&ADS_Android_MigrationPopupExperiment_V9:::a&WebApps_FacebookPixelUpgrade_V5:::b&AAExperiment_V8:::b&ADS_Airbnb_Inline_V4:::a&TurnFeatureTests:::on&Car_NewGrouping_V6:::b&FlightsHeroImage_CA_11_07_2016_36_20_V2:::b; ssassociate=; abgroup=60235545; X-Mapping-rrsqbjcb=n585oyq9u4p7nk2fv507dsrhhi1pltmx; X-Mapping-ecilpojl=9E5E3BBB2B3FA2A8291041A36D26B30B; ASP.NET_SessionId=fssk9taz0; firstvisit=overlay:::show; preferences=ed299c745b634f30aa2a3b7dcccfd0da; ver=28; settings=acql:::true; acq=1fd352cc-279f-4dc2-a954-37853c616f30|1fd352cc-279f-4dc2-a954-37853c616f30; D_SID=58.62.101.199:dRyPUsEgmhXYBvyhDxJj7GzRPnlfOUHzJzAnRXajZY0; D_PID=3AED90B8-ECEA-3EF3-B973-F37429C83E7E; D_IID=E43BB637-1A16-368D-A625-58F0E91A36FD; D_UID=3037B054-1AD0-3C17-8490-8411B36BC03A; D_HID=+BqDJPwbNFM4MRZHc29rJefcBqY92FMgMh08SGOIsS0; D_ZID=24F50A77-4902-3C47-8362-73C6C1746AE0; D_ZUID=0C1487D6-1F62-3039-87EE-F7588AE36B04; DAPROPS="bjs.webGl:1|bjs.geoLocation:1|bjs.webSqlDatabase:0|bjs.indexedDB:1|bjs.webSockets:1|bjs.localStorage:1|bjs.sessionStorage:1|bjs.webWorkers:1|bjs.applicationCache:1|bjs.supportBasicJavaScript:1|bjs.modifyDom:1|bjs.modifyCss:1|bjs.supportEvents:1|bjs.supportEventListener:1|bjs.xhr:1|bjs.supportConsoleLog:1|bjs.json:1|bjs.deviceOrientation:0|bjs.deviceMotion:1|bjs.touchEvents:0|bjs.querySelector:1|bjs.battery:1|bhtml.canvas:1|bhtml.video:1|bhtml.audio:1|bhtml.svg:1|bhtml.inlinesvg:1|bcss.animations:1|bcss.columns:1|bcss.transforms:1|bcss.transitions:1|idisplayColorDepth:24|bcookieSupport:1|sdevicePixelRatio:1.5|sdeviceAspectRatio:16/9|bflashCapable:1|baccessDom:1|buserMedia:1"; sspref=authcheckedexpiry:::1477233029685; _ga=GA1.3.46831674.1477227536; sstrack=ed299c74-5b63-4f30-aa2a-3b7dcccfd0da; ssinitacq=4409777b-dc68-4693-8286-aba764120bcc; __gads=ID=e987795b8f18bbda:T=1477227542:S=ALNI_MYHiuv2Tp5sUN7nbu5RwdC7YNlUQA; mp_mixpanel__c=0; mp_grappler__c=0; ADRUM=s=1477232872251&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.skyscanner.com.hk%2Ftransport%2Fflights%2Fcan%2Fchc%2F170604%2Fairfares-from-guangzhou-to-christchurch-in-june-2017.html%3F-825507930; sssessionid=wrs8suvjo; _gat=1; _gat_uatracker=1; mp_2434748954c30ccc5017faa456fa3d38_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%223b0417d6-b970-47ac-f23e-07d6e176fc96%22%2C%22User%20Locale%22%3A%20%22EN-GB%22%2C%22User%20Market%22%3A%20%22HK%22%2C%22User%20Currency%22%3A%20%22HKD%22%2C%22New%20User%22%3A%20false%2C%22Internal%20User%22%3A%20%22FALSE%22%2C%22Mobile%22%3A%20%22FALSE%22%2C%22Tablet%22%3A%20%22FALSE%22%2C%22OS%20Version%22%3A%20%22NT%2010.0%22%2C%22Device%20Model%22%3A%20%22FIREFOX%20-%20WINDOWS%22%2C%22Browser%20Version%22%3A%20%2249.0%22%2C%22Cookie%20Policy%20Alert%20Acknowledged%22%3A%20false%2C%22Skyscanner%20User%20Id%22%3A%20%228fe29164-539e-4ce4-8de4-80c8f5325834%22%2C%22Skyscanner%20UTID%22%3A%20%228fe29164-539e-4ce4-8de4-80c8f5325834%22%2C%22Skyscanner%20UTID%20Status%22%3A%201%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D',
  "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":1,
  "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0" 
 }
};


var req = https.request(options,function(res){
 console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
   console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    

   res.on('data', function(d){
        process.stdout.write(d); 

   });

  });

req.write(postData);

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e){
  console.error(e);
});
```

And below is the result from window-cmd.

```js
statusCode: 200
headers: { server: 'nginx',
  'content-type': 'text/html',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  expires: 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache, private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  'surrogate-control': 'no-store, bypass-cache',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-length': '785',
  date: 'Sun, 23 Oct 2016 15:50:44 GMT',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
       �Tmo�6�l�
F#�N��E���24���)�ɣŌ"U�r�����tmB�<�w��o�>E���u�ݪWk����(�n���    �M�i�8��/>F�v>[Lg�4���gw�?O�l�~����( r�4P�çR�ӈQ�fF{kT��h�F9}�t)�P�#8mpc�
^i� �w{.J8E$A�Q���Aɐ���/�����r���Y��� ��*�Jc.����>-�a?���Gi�-ծ0��B�U�]̨�Y�����yL�4caM�W%ի�̔؇h2�YVZ�a��s�wIr�㧼Tޥ�O4/F,��[�)iĝm��5(YjAu��]J�u.���ɫFm ����,�U�)�Ҕ��ph�T��R��10��Vx-�Q|����]z��29ǃA�
'ɴ�'W���nn&ɔܝ��1��  e�'��K..Ho�{BǬ,<�Ui�����tMw���(5���΋�ܼ�lڭ�����SC�@�n�       =�(M�q�����o�3��C�9�7G]B��q��<t��^w2���E��0c�U�Cu�C�M $*��H   �I�O�BJf�Bf��4|3��@2���Z^Rq���Q���7�_B�ב���vو0X�\�j��J1j4N�p۠��ɥT�W�Lrz�nɽ-y�Ooo�Z2
```

Comment: This looks like you are logging the bufferedStream and not the actual response. Could you please post the function where you log the response?

Comment: @nicovank I just use ```process.stdout.write(d); ``` to log the result and expect to show on cmd.

Comment: I have post all the codes on this question.